# Object from JSON.parse can not change property value

Tags: javascript

i am getting frustrated because i have a method which receives a Json in the body.

```
var user = JSON.parse(req.body.user);
console.log("user: " + user);  //1
console.log("user image: " + user.image); //2
```

When i check the terminal u got these:

1:

```
user: {"email":"abc@outlook.com","firstname":"ABC","lastname":"DEF","lastname2":"GHI","phone":"999999999","doctype":"1","numdoc":"999999999","password":"12345678","image":"-","sessionToken":"-","roles":[]}
```

but in second line I got:

2:

```
user image: undefined
```

In another point, I tried to change the image property, and I got these:}

```
nombre = 'abc';
user.image = nombre;  
console.log("filename:" + nombre);
console.log("new name: " + user.image );
```

In terminal I got:

```
filename:abc
new name: undefined
```

So my question is... an object from JSON.parse function can't be changed?

What am I doing wrong.

Regards

Comment: "So my question is... an object from JSON.parse function can't be changed?" oh no, they definitely can, you can verify that in 2 seconds in your browser console. I cannot replicate your problem. In particular, your second case could only happen if the object in question was [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), which is not the case here. If you're doing something wrong, it isn't in the code you posted.

Comment: Yeah, that's very weird... i will still check...

Comment: How are you handling the network request? I'm wondering if there is an issue where you are getting the response and trying to manipulate the result in a different scope. It may be helpful if you provided more context with this request.

Comment: Please do `console.log(typeof user)`. I bet it's still a **string, not an object** (and you're getting a weird network request), as otherwise `"user: " + user` should have printed `user: [object Object]` instead of that json text.

Comment: I did a console.log(typeof user_) and it says is a String. That's weird... i had to do Json.Pase twice and i could do the process well... i will check again the sender code... Thank you !!!